# How to run a mounted function everytime the window is resized and then destroy the event listener

Tags: vue.js

I have the following mounted function that I would then like to run every time the window is resized. I would also like to use destroy() to delete the event after its run. Any help would be greatly received.

```
mounted() {
    const modalHeight = this.$refs.modal.getBoundingClientRect().height
    const wrapperHeight = 
this.$refs.modalWrapper.getBoundingClientRect().height

if (wrapperHeight > modalHeight) {
  this.$refs.modal.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    const diffHeight = wrapperHeight - modalHeight
    const multiplier = diffHeight / 100
    const steps = 100 / modalHeight
    const shiftPerc = Math.floor(e.clientY * steps)

    this.$refs.modalWrapper.style.transform = `translateY(${multiplier * shiftPerc * -1}px)`
  })
}
```

},

Answer (score 2):

You could move the function to a separate section within `methods` and add/remove the event listener with it as the reference.

Also, be advised that since `resize` events can fire at a high rate, the event handler shouldn't execute computationally expensive operations. Instead, it is recommended to [throttle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize#Examples) or [debounce](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) the event.

An example using [lodash's `.debounce()`](https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce) function.

```js
export default {
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', _.debounce(this.updateModal, 250));
  },

  methods: {
    updateModal() {
      const modalHeight = this.$refs.modal.getBoundingClientRect().height;
      const wrapperHeight = this.$refs.modalWrapper.getBoundingClientRect().height;

      if (wrapperHeight > modalHeight) {
        this.$refs.modal.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
          const diffHeight = wrapperHeight - modalHeight;
          const multiplier = diffHeight / 100;
          const steps = 100 / modalHeight;
          const shiftPerc = Math.floor(e.clientY * steps);

          this.$refs.modalWrapper.style.transform = `translateY(${multiplier * shiftPerc * -1}px)`;
        });
      }
    }
  },

  destroy() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.updateModal);
  }
})
```

Comment: `window.removeEventListener('resize', this.updateModal /* this is not the original debounced function */)`

Comment: no need for jquery they said. it will be fun they said. all this junk you can do in jquery with few lines of code